# Observe(and prosess) LiveData inside my ViewModel. And only then pass if to view, by splitting to smaller LaveData objects

Tags: android, android-room, android-livedata

I want to:

1. Fetch data to my ViewModel.
2. Split it on LiveData objects.
3. Do some stuff with it, and only then pass it to my view.

Some user options depends on each other. For example, changing *mGender* must change *mAge*
So, that is what i'v done

DAO

```
@Query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE _id = :id")
LiveData<User> getUserById(int id);
```

ViewModel

```
private MediatorLiveData<Integer> mUnitSystem = new MediatorLiveData<>();
private MediatorLiveData<Integer> mAge = new MediatorLiveData<>();
private MediatorLiveData<Integer> mGender = new MediatorLiveData<>();
private MediatorLiveData<Double> mHeight = new MediatorLiveData<>();

public UserSettingsViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
    super(application);
    mData = Injector.getDataReporitory(application);
    MediatorLiveData<User> userMediatorLiveData = new MediatorLiveData<>();
    userMediatorLiveData.addSource(mData.getUser(1), new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
            mUnitSystem.postValue(user.getUnitSystem());
            mAge.postValue(user.getAge());
            mGender.postValue(user.getGender());
            mHeight.postValue(user.getHeight());
        }
    });
    userMediatorLiveData.observeForever(new Observer<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable User user) {
        }
    });
    mGender.addSource(mUnitSystem, new Observer<Integer>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable Integer integer) {

            mAge.postValue(integer + 10);
        }
    });
}

public LiveData<Integer> getGender() {
    return mGender;
}
public LiveData<Integer> getAge() {
    return mAge;
}
public LiveData<Integer> getUnitSystem() {
    return mUnitSystem;
}

// setter to them
```

So, its working. But, i really confused about observeForever() inside ViewModel. I know that is not recommended by Google.

I want more clean approach.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: use Transformations.switchMap

Comment: Transformations.switchMap will return me User POJO.
`mHeight = Transformations.switchMap(mData.getUser(), input -> null);`

Comment: sry Transformations.map ,also watch this video will help you to understand how to use livedata  http://newsvideo.su/tech/video/272065